# How to add a record to table when hitting save using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a table loaded from database. I want whenever the user enters a record. The record should be added to the table without refreshing the whole page.this should be in the AJAX function. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//save button listener  
$("#save").click(function(){
//receiving data entered by user from design.php        
     var name = $('#name').val();
     var email = $('#email').val();
     var telephone = $('#telephone').val();
     var username = $('#username').val();
     var password = $('#password').val(); 
     
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   url: 'contactData.php',             
   data:{"name":name,"telephone":telephone,"email":email, "username":username, "password":password},
  // dataType:'json',
   success: function(data) {
       ssword);
       var result = JSON.parse(data);
       $("#validate").html(result.msg);
      
                           }        
  });//end of ajax
     });//end of listener
        });//end of javascript
```

And here is my table(PHP):

```
<div class="table">
<?php 
 //connect to the database
   $username="root";
   $password="";
   $host="localhost";
   $connector = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
      or die("Unable to connect");
  $selected = mysql_select_db("mysql", $connector)
    or die("Unable to connect");

  //execute the SQL query and return records
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");
  ?>
<table border="2" style= "background-color: #99ffcc; color: #761a9b; margin: 0 auto;">
<thead>
  <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      <tbody>
        <?php
          while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
          {
           echo "<tr>
                 <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['telephone']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['username']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['password']}</td>
                 </tr>\n";
           }
        ?>
     </tbody>    
   </tr>
</thead>
</table>
</div>
```

How can I refresh the table in the AJAX function?

Comment: New ajax request which returns table

Comment: Just `[table].appendChild(...)` in the Ajax success callback? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13871627/246342)

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your tbody.

```
<tbody class="res-container">
```

In your AJAX call, you can try this.

```
data1: {name: name, telephone: telephone, email: email, username: username, password: password},
success: function(response) {
    var html = '<tr>';
    html = html + '<td>' + this.data1.name + '</td>';
    html = html + '<td>' + this.data1.email + '</td>';
    html = html + '<td>' + this.data1.telephone + '</td>';
    html = html + '<td>' + this.data1.username + '</td>';
    html = html + '<td>' + this.data1.password + '</td>';
    html = html + '</tr>';
    $('.res-container').append(html);
}
```

`this.data1.name` is basically accessing the ajax data1 property. So whatever name you assign there, same should be used here.

UPDATE:

I have modified the code to update the correct values. I cannot use `this.data` inside success. So I created another property called `data1` and used `this.data1` to access it.

Comment: Sorry friend!!! (Exclamation added because comment requires minimum number of characters)

Comment: it is adding a row but with undefined values why is that??