# How to add row to the beginning of table using javascript

Tags: javascript

I clone a row and append it to the end of a table the following function add_record().
My question is how to append it to the beginning of the table.
I tried using

```
$("#main_table_id tbody").prepend(clone)
```

and

```
$("#main_table_id tbody").prepend(clone.innerHtml)
```

but it didn't work.

```
function add_record(){      
        var row = document.getElementById("template_no_1_id"); 
        var table = document.getElementById("main_table_id"); 
        var clone = row.cloneNode(true); 
        clone.id = "newID"; 
        table.appendChild(clone); 
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript Add Table Row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870348/javascript-add-table-row)

Comment: the possible duplicate answer is replacong all innerHtml of a table. I would like an answer that append only the first row since the table is big.

Answer (score 2):

Use native function insertRow.

```
<table id="TableA">
<tr>
<td>Old top row</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">

function addRow(tableID) {
  // Get a reference to the table
  var tableRef = document.getElementById(tableID);

  // Insert a row in the table at row index 0
  var newRow   = tableRef.insertRow(0);

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
  var newCell  = newRow.insertCell(0);

  // Append a text node to the cell
  var newText  = document.createTextNode('New top row');
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

// Call addRow() with the ID of a table
addRow('TableA');

</script>
```

Credit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.insertRow