# Adding a new row to table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

When the user clicks the add new button a new row should be added to the bottom of the table, but when I click the button, nothing happens. The script looks fine to me and I've tried to find a solution for hours.

```js
  function addRow(tableID) {
                var table = document.getElementById(tableID),
                    row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length),
                    i;
                for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
                    createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
                }
            }
```

```html
 <head>
        <style>
         table, th, td{
            border: 1px solid black;
         }  
        </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <table id="countries">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</td>
                    <th>Code</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Algeria</td>
                    <td>213</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="button" onclick="addRow('countries');">Add New</button>
       
    </body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Add Table Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870348/javascript-add-table-row)

Comment: I can see that you are calling a function named `createCell` in your for loop. But, I cannot see that where you defined it. It may be because you haven't defined that function and you get an error. Check your console.

Comment: @Bora you're right I hadn't defined createCell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```js
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID),
      row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length),
      i;
  for (i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
      createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
  }
}

function createCell(cell, text, style) {
  var div = document.createElement('div'), 
  txt = document.createTextNode(text);    
  div.appendChild(txt);                   
  div.setAttribute('class', style);        
  div.setAttribute('className', style);    
  cell.appendChild(div);                   
}
```

```html
<html>
  <title>Test</title>
  <head>
    <style>
     table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
     }  
    </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table id="countries">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>Country</td>
          <th>Code</td>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Algeria</td>
          <td>213</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" onclick="addRow('countries');">Add New</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked and I was able to add user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can done this with very little code using JQuery. check below code here :-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add").click(function(){
    $("#countries tbody tr:last-child").after("<tr><td>Data</td><td>data</td></tr>")
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td{
        border: 1px solid black;
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="countries">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Country</th>
                <th>Code</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Algeria</td>
                <td>213</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button class="add" type="button">Add New</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is what you are looking for,

```
    <script>
        function addRow(tableID) {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);    // get tableById
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;    // get row count
            var cellCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;    // get cell count
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);   // create row
            for(var i =0; i <= cellCount; i++){
                createCell(row.insertCell(i), i, 'row');
            }
        }
    </script>
```